# Use keys defined in a configuration file

Tags: c#

I need to use the keys defined in a configuration file in the following code:

```
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.D1:
                if (keyIsDown[Keys.D1]) return;
                if (beatload1.Text == "Waiting 01.wav")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No beat loaded.");
                    return;
                }
                try
                {
                    keyIsDown[Keys.D1] = true;
                    Beat1.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
                    Bass.BASS_ChannelGetInfo(stream1, info);
                    if (b_toggler1 == "0")
                    {
                        if (!String.Equals(info.filename, path1))
                        {
                            Bass.BASS_StreamFree(stream1);
                            stream1 = Foo.GetStream1(path1);
                        }
                        Bass.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(stream1, BASSAttribute.BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, vol);
                        Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(stream1, true);
                    }
                    else if (b_toggler1 == "1")
                    {
                        if (!String.Equals(info.filename, path37))
                        {
                            Bass.BASS_StreamFree(stream1);
                            stream1 = Foo.GetStream1(path37);
                        }
                        Bass.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(stream1, BASSAttribute.BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, vol);
                        Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(stream1, true);
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File has been moved." + "\n" + "Please relocate it now!");
                }
                break;
            case Keys.D2:
                if (keyIsDown[Keys.D2]) return;
                if (beatload2.Text == "Waiting 02.wav")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No beat loaded.");
                    return;
                }
                try
                {
                    keyIsDown[Keys.D2] = true;
                    Beat2.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
                    Bass.BASS_ChannelGetInfo(stream2, info);
                    if (b_toggler1 == "0")
                    {
                        if (!String.Equals(info.filename, path2))
                        {
                            Bass.BASS_StreamFree(stream2);
                            stream2 = Foo.GetStream2(path2);
                        }
                        Bass.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(stream2, BASSAttribute.BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, vol);
                        Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(stream2, true);
                    }
                    if (b_toggler1 == "1")
                    {
                        if (!String.Equals(info.filename, path38))
                        {
                            Bass.BASS_StreamFree(stream2);
                            stream2 = Foo.GetStream2(path38);
                        }
                        Bass.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(stream2, BASSAttribute.BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, vol);
                        Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(stream2, true);
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File has been moved." + "\n" + "Please relocate it now!");
                }
                break;
        }
```

The configuration file containing the keys that should be used looks like this:

```
<add key="x36_key1" value="D1"/>
<add key="x36_key2" value="D2"/>
```

So instead of the key being defined manually in the code, how could I make it so that it would be defined in the configuration file instead?

Comment: Where do you plan to use the values that you read from your configuration file?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Where "Keys.D1" or "Keys.D2" are required. That would be here `case Keys.D1:`, here `keyIsDown[Keys.D1] = true;` here `case Keys.D2:` and here `keyIsDown[Keys.D2] = true;`